# Error while use dictionary values on for command in python

Tags: python

I write the following code to select a random value of an existing key. When I run the code the below error is shown.

```
graph = defaultdict(dict) 
graph={3: [4, 7], 4: [3, 5], 7: [1, 3], 1: [7, 2], 2: [1, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [5, 2]}
start_vertex=7
for vertex in random.choice(graph[start_vertex]):
   if vertex not in apath:
       extended_apath = find_path(vertex, end_vertex, apath)
```

The error: [image: This Error has been shown]

Comment: This code is half-baked. Half of the symbols that you're using are not defined/declared/initialized anywhere, spaces and indentations are all messed up, and what's the point in doing `graph=` twice when only the second assignment counts???

Comment: Where's apath? Or at least an example of it?

Comment: you need to include enough code for somebody to replicate the error

Comment: The problem is that `choice` will return a single integer, so indeed you can not iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option II**

If you REALLY want to get random numbers based on sub-lists in your dictionary, you can try a different method to get that

```
    # randomise from dictionary element
    vertices = graph[start_vertex]

    for vertex in random.sample(vertices, len(vertices)):
        print(vertex)
```

**Option I**

Just remove `start_vertex` from the loop since you are trying to randomly choose from `graph` dictionary

```
    random.choice(graph)
```

Like this

```
    graph = defaultdict(dict)

    # BE AWARE OF unconditionally re-declaring graph without having used it
    graph = {3: [4, 7], 4: [3, 5], 7: [1, 3], 1: [7, 2], 2: [1, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [5, 2]}
    start_vertex = 7

    for vertex in random.choice(graph):
        if vertex not in apath:
            extended_apath = find_path(vertex, end_vertex, apath)
```

Hope it helps (:

Answer (score 0):

Try random.choices instead of random.choice

```
graph = defaultdict(dict) 
graph={3: [4, 7], 4: [3, 5], 7: [1, 3], 1: [7, 2], 2: [1, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [5, 2]}
start_vertex=7
for vertex in random.choices(graph[start_vertex]):
   if vertex not in apath:
       extended_apath = find_path(vertex, end_vertex, apath)
```